# Why do I need Spring Boot `messages.properties` instead of just `messages_en.properties`?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-internationalization

I'm following [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization) and it says to name the default messages file as `messages.properties`. Why can't I name it `messages_en.properties` and set the default locale to English?

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return slr;
}
```

This doesn't work (have to hard stop and restart the server each time `message.properties` is renamed - dynamic reload fails to pick up the changes). It will print out `default` text with a tag like `<spring:message code="oops" text="default"/>` because it can't find `messages_en.properties`.

In fact, when I set my browser default language to French and have `messages_fr.properties`, and restart the server, it is also failing to find the keys for French as well.

Not using Thymeleaf. No need to allow user-selectable language.

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.17.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ (Only one instance of the world 'internationalization', and only regarding application properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using [`AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.20.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-localeresolver-acceptheader) instead.

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver ahlr = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    ahlr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return ahlr;
}
```

I thought the guide said it will search for the locale in the session, cookie, or header, but they were only saying that different sub-classes implement those features separately.

> The LocaleResolver interface has implementations that determine the current locale based on the session, cookies, the Accept-Language header, or a fixed value.

I fixed the live reload problem by setting this [application property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.17.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties), at least for debugging:

```
spring.messages.cache-seconds=1
```

I also set this property so as not to clutter up my `src/main/resources` folder, so I could move all the message files into the `locales/` sub-directory.

```
spring.messages.basename=locales/messages
```

Comment: This is the default resolver used by Spring Boot and with this you cannot have, user selectable languages. As the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver`. For that you need the `SessionLocaleResolver` or `CookieLocaleResolver` (which if nothing found in the session or cookie default to the accept-header and finally the default).

Comment: Hmm, `SessionLocaleResolver` wasn't defaulting to the Accept-Language header, as there were no session attributes, so it must be broken. It's an error page; no need for user-selectable language.

Comment: It will do a fall back if no default-locale has been selected. You are setting a default of English so that will be used. The fallback to the accept-header is only when you don't set this.

Comment: You contradict yourself. 1st you say it searches session/cookie, then `Accept-Language` header, and finally the default. 2nd you say it uses default locale before `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: I’m not contradicting myself. As stated first it check the session, then depending on if the default locale has been set it will return that if that isn’t set it will lookup the value in the accept header. If it does a fallback to the accept-header depends on the fact if you have set a default or not (the accept-header is used in the last one).