# Why doesn't Spring use locale `en` when given `en_US`?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-internationalization

Related but not the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53366295/148844). I have

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver ahlr = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    ahlr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return ahlr;
}
```

And my browser is sending `Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9`. I have `messages_en.properties` (but not `messages.properties`). I get this error

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'title' for locale 'en_US'.
```

I know I can fix it by renaming `messages_en.properties` to `messages.properties`, but why doesn't Spring Boot find the `en` locale when given `en_US`?

I expect this to be a problem when someone has `fr_FR` locale instead of just `fr`. Must I really duplicate the locales for every single country?

How can I make Spring smarter to use the language if the specific country locale is not found?

Spring Boot 1.5.13, Spring Core 4.3.17

Comment: Because you need the `message.properties` (can be empty) to add a proper `MessageSource`. It will then use the `messages_en.properties`. But the `messages.properties` is required as the ultimate fallback (and the trigger for Spring Boot to enable a pre-configured `MessageSource`).

Comment: I'm assuming you are using Spring Boot (as the tags state). Spring Boot uses the existence of the plain `<basename>.properties` to add a pre-configured `MessageSource`. If that file isn't present, there is no `MessageSource` and messages aren't resolved. Also the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` is already the default, instead of configuring it adding `spring.mvc.locale=en` to the `application.properties` is enough. So unless you aren't configuring things yourself  or you aren't showing the full configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Spring Boot to auto configure a `MessageSource` it [checks the existence](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L93) of the `<basename>.properties`. If that exists a `MessageSource` is configured, else nothing is configured and no messages will be resolved.

To fix add an empty `<basename>.properties` to `src/main/resource` to have the `MessageSource` automatically configured.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an empty `messages.properties` fixed this issue as given in the [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53417837/why-doesnt-spring-use-locale-en-when-given-en-us?noredirect=1#comment93710408_53417837). Very strange and non-intuitive error message. If the comment is given as an answer, I will accept that.